# how does the output became 2? don't understand

Tags: java, switch-statement, coding-style

```
public class Ex33 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3, result = 4;
        switch (x + 3) {
            case 6: result = 0;
            case 7: result = 1;
            default: result += 1;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Don't understand how the answer became 2?

Comment: for future reference: post code, not images of code. Don't just say "don't understand", say what you don't understand. what did you expect it to be, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the absence of `break;` in each case, your case statements are falling through and fail to come out of the loop. All your cases are being applied, hence resulting in `result = 2`.

The correctly formatted code will look like this:

```
    int x =3, result=4;

    switch (x+4){
        case 6: 
            result = 0;
            break;

        case 7: 
            result = 1;
            break;

        default: 
            result+=1;
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: how do you know this code is correct? It is possible the code was correct, the OP just didn't understand the code.

Comment: Missing the break statement in switch cases is a common mistake. This fact, accompanied by the way the OP's question is framed, indicates that this code is what he wanted.

Comment: for all we know, he was shown code that he doesn't understand. it's the output he expected, doesn't mean his "wanting" is relevant

Comment: then we can all wait for him to come online and clarify

Answer (score 1):

`case` statements "fall through" without `break`

```
case 7: result = 1;   // <-- no break, so
default: result += 1; // <-- happens after case 7
```

This is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) behavior

> Another point of interest is the `break` statement. Each `break` statement terminates the enclosing `switch` statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the `switch` block. The `break` statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks *fall through*: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered

Answer (score 1):

All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered. 
put a break operation that works!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `break` statement after each `case` if you want to stop other case statement from executing . So the equivalent code to get result value as 1 is :

```
int x =3, result=4;
        switch (x+4){
            case 6: result = 0;
            break;
            case 7: result = 1;
            break;
            default: result+=1;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
```

Read **Some Important rules for switch statements** part from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-statement-in-java/)

Comment: "have to" is a bold statement, since whether or not you have to put the break statement, depends on your requirements

Comment: @Stultuske yes correct.